# How can I configure glassfish javamail sessions to read email?

Tags: glassfish, jakarta-mail

Is there a way to configure glassfish javamail sessions to read mails from gmail? For example, I want to set username, password as properties in glassfish and avoid code like this `store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "username", "password");`

P.S. I heard it would be a good practice if I use JCA to do this. But I don't know how to do it neither.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JCA.  You need to create a JavaMail Session resource as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/giowr/index.html), for example:

```
asadmin --user admin create-javamail-resource --mailhost="imap.gmail.com" --mailuser="GMAIL_USERNAME" --fromaddress="GMAIL_ADDRESS" --description="A new JavaMail Session!" --property="mail.imap.password=YOUR_PASSWORD:mail.imap.ssl.enable=true" "mail/newsession"
```

Then lookup or inject "mail/newsession" in your code to get the Session object, get the Store object from the Session, and call `store.connect();`